# Callback in chrome.tts.speak?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech

I am trying to call a callback function after `chrome.tts.speak` has finished the speech, and there is a nice argument space for that. But, after looking for more detail about it, very disappointingly, this is what [the document](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tts.html#method-speak) says:

> ***callback ( optional function )***
>   　　Called right away, before speech finishes.

And I don't want it to be called right away. I want it *after* the speech is finished. So is it possible? Any method is welcomed. (but not so *"hacky"*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same page, it mentions `onEvent` (as part of `options`):

> ***onEvent ( optional function )***
>   　　This function is called with events that occur in the process of speaking the utterance.
>   　　**Parameters**
>   　　***event ( `TtsEvent` )***
>   　　　　The update event from the text-to-speech engine indicating the status of this utterance.

`TtsEvent` has a `type` property, which can be `end` to mark the speech ending. Put it together:

```
chrome.tts.speak("Hello, world!", {
    requiredEventTypes: ['end'],
    onEvent: function(event) {
        if(event.type === 'end') {
            alert('Speech ended.');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Umm..., I tried it and it doesn't work... It still call the callback right after it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: please share you successful code or a link to it, that will help others.

Comment: @Hugolpz - I just used the code [icktoofay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/200291/icktoofay) posted in his answer and it works.